# LoadingView из нескольких методов

Tags: java, android, mvp

Использую Moxy для реализации MVP.

Первый вопрос:
Такая ситуация. Есть активити(вью) к которой привязываются 2 презентера.

Есть два презентера и в обоих из них выполняется запрос на сервер(в один момент), в этот момент оба презентера отправляют во вью команду показать LoadingView и соответственно при завершении отправляют команду скрыть LoadingView.

Во вью, LoadingView один для всех.

Коллизие в том что: первый презентер может отправить команду на закрытие, в тот момент пока второй презентер все ещё получает данные. Логичнее скрывать LoadingView после выполнения запросов в обоих презентерах.

Может есть best practices как решить этот вопрос?

Второй вопрос:
Мой LoadingView это cancelable  Dialog с прозрачным темным фоном.
При вызове show, я передаю туда disposable(rxJava) и если пользователь закрывает этот LoadingView то происходит disposable.dispose() т.к. операция далее не актуальна. Практикуете такое? Как подружить такое с первым вопросом?)

Comment: а что за дичь с двумя презентерами, почему не 5 или 17 ? неужели одного не достаточно и как они "параллельно" работают и зачем оно так ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Передаете событие завершения загрузки из одного презентера в другой через вьюху, потому что в ней у вас есть ссылки на презентеры. В презентере проверяете, если запрос текущего презентера еще идёт, то оставляете загрузочный диалог, если нет, то убираете. Такой же механизм надо сделать и в другом презентере. Так можно сделать, если от двух презентеров избавиться невозможно, но если есть возможность перевести логику отображения вью в один презентер лучше сделать так.
2. Такое не практикуется. Disposable это объект презентера и вьюхе вообще не нужно знать о том, как вы делаете свои запросы в сеть, а тем более управлять их жизненным циклом. Поэтому ивент, когда пользователь нажимает отмену нужно передавать в презентер и там делать dispose или clear

Если после таких решений у вас появился дублирующийся код в презентерах, то можно его вынести в абстрактный класс презентер и потом наследоваться.